# How to package npm module with AudioWorklet?

Tags: npm, vite, audio-worklet, audioworkletprocessor

I've built an AudioWorklet that imports an npm module. This works during runtime but fails when compiled. My understanding (but new to Worklets and Web Workers) is that the AudioWorklet code needs to be self-contained and can't pull the import in production.

Can we compile the AudioWorklet with the npm imports at build time (or something else of better practice)? Using Vite for frontend compilation.

The following is a simplified example of my Worklet, but no real code to shorten the example.

```js
import { ToolWASM } from 'tool/dist/wasm.es.js'
import Tool from 'tool/dist/core.es.js'

let tool = new Tool(ToolWASM)

class SampleProcess extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.tool = tool
  }

  process() {
    this.tool.doSomething()
    return false
  }
}

registerProcessor('sample-processor', SampleProcess)
```

Answer (score 1):

From my attempts to do a similar trick with vite simply `ctx.audioWorklet.addModule(new URL('./worklet.ts', import.meta.url))` does the job at least in development build.

To make it really work it should be handled as per vite's docs for workers. See [import with query suffixes](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#import-with-query-suffixes)

```
import workletUrl from './worklet?worker&url'
import wasmUrl from 'shared/shared_bg.wasm?url'
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip. This one worked!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up coming up with used Rollup to achieve it. Ended up adding a basic Rollup setup to bundle the file during runtime and compile time. I did it this way as trying to incorporate it within Vite affected the plug-and-play setup Vite has with my Tauri app.

This approach allowed me to run my `rollup` completely separately and ahead of the building of the rest of the app.

The `rollup.config.js` was set up as follows.

```js
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace'

export default {
  input: 'src/worklets/file.js',

  output: {
    file: 'src/bundles/file-bundle.js',
    format: 'iife',
  },

  plugins: [
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      preferBuiltins: false,
    }),
    commonjs(),
    replace({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
    }),
  ],
}
```

In my `package.json` created a few scripts that get run. For anyone curious, the `build:<name>` and `dev:<name>` are using `npm-run-all`, so the scripts you are seeing are part of several that run either sequentially (`build`) or parallel (`dev`).

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build:bundle": "yarn rollup",
  ...
  "dev:bundle": "yarn rollup --watch",
  ...
  "rollup": "rollup --c",
}
```